# Setting BaseURL for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I set my `baseurl` to:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/
```

in the `application/config/config.php file` as asked by [the installation instructions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html).

I was following [this tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html). However, when I type in the url: `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/pages/view` , I get the the following error:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost 7/27/2012 11:14:39 PM Apache/2.2.12 (Win32) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.12 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.0
>   mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0

I found the following contents in `.htaccess` file in the path of `E:\WEB D\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.1.2\application`:

> Deny from all

I am totally new to the CodeIgniter framework. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please include the entire error message in your question. It shouldn't just say "Object Not Found."

Comment: Are the files and classes all named properly?

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file somewhere?  If so can you post it?

Comment: i named all the files and classes as mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: yeah .. `.htacess` file was there .. I posted it in the edited question.

Comment: Ok..that .htaccess is weird, ignoring it for now, where are the files all stored?  I am assuming you are using xampp\wamp so it would be something like C:\xampp\htdocs\codeignitor\

Comment: yeah.. I have mentioned the path of my `.htaccess` file too ..

Comment: ok well assuming localhost is pointing to E:\WEBD\xampp\htdocs\ then you need to rename the folder CodeIgniter_2.1.2 to codeigniter as you have set in your config file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, well for anyone wondering the final solution to this was that the directories were not properly named.  When creating a local server it is important to put the contents of the files in the correct folder.

So if you have `http://localhost/codeigniter` then the directory should be setup as `\path\to\webdirectory\root\codeigniter` or in this case: `E:\WEBD\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter`

Answer (score 4):

try edit your .htaccess file became like this below, and put .htaccess file in your root application folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: godlike answer to me :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your php errors are visible.

I had this issue as well when trying to set the base_url for Code Igniter when I was working off localhost. I had a look in the htaccess file, checked that mod_rewrite was switched on, tried altering the base_url but all failed.

The solution was to make sure that the environment was set to development in the main index.php file and to ensure that $config['log_threshold'] = 4; is set in config.php.

After that my php errors showed up. I'd forgotten to switch the development environment for the new website build.